# Does CLOCKS_PER_SEC mean each computer will have different concept of time?

Tags: c++, time

We are running some benchmarks and we are noticing that `function foo` which calls `function bar` and waits for a response is taking **less** time than `function bar`. Foo resides on the client, which is a separate physical machine and bar resides on the server which is a separate machine, and communication is through a TCP server. We are using `<ctime>` and we are calling `clock()` like so.

```
/*
* resides on client machine
*/
foo ()
{
    clock_t start,stop;
    start = clock();
    /*
     * Blocking TCP call to bar() on server
     * Uses callback functions
    */
    stop = clock();
    std::cout<<stop-start;
}
/*
 * Function on server which executes some could and returns
 * it's run time to the client machine
 */
bar ()
{
    clock_t start,stop;
    start = clock();
    /*connect to international space station and back*/
    stop = clock();
    std::cout<<stop-start;
}
foo();
bar();
foo() - bar();
```

The output we are getting is something like

```
100000
200000
-100000
```

We suspect that the issue is that one CPU's sense of time is faster than the other's and is causing this mismatch. What is the best way to get meaningful time metrics (ie. based on human time, not abstract CPU speed).

Comment: CLOCKS_PER_SEC is defined for a specific compiler, so yes, it could be different on different systems, or  it could be different on the same system for different compilers..

Comment: @NeilButterworth from my experience, CLOCKS_PER_SEC is always 1,000,000

Comment: The C++ Standard makes no such guarantee.

Comment: If I want to get meaningful time, ie. this pc took 30ms to compute (+/- a few ns for ppm drift) while this other one took 45ms, how does one achieve that?

Comment: `clock` is not wall time. It's processor time.

Comment: It means that every compiler has its own sense of time.  But whomever created its C library tends to know enough about the machine.  It is certainly not "always 1,000,000", C++ can generally count faster thanks to std::chrono.

Comment: On my Windows computer I find `#define CLOCKS_PER_SEC  ((clock_t)1000)`

Answer (score 1):

You very well may be comparing apples to oranges. There is no guarantee that your two machines are using the same resolution for `clock()`. Perhaps the more useful thing would be to ensure that your timing numbers are in consistent units, like seconds.

```
std::cout << (stop-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

Or, you might want to try using Modern C++ and `<chrono>`

```
using std::chrono;
auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
...
auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
std::cout << duration_cast< duration<float> >(stop-start).count()
          << " seconds" << std::endl;
```

(although it's worth noting that `high_resolution_clock` may be implemented as `system_clock`; `steady_clock` is specifically designed for timing such as you are trying to do. There may also be non-portable solutions with even greater resolution that are hardware/OS-specific.)

Comment: It **is** comparing apples and oranges. Even if `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` would be the same value, you're still comparing the CPU time consumed by the sending and receiving process. `<chrono>` is the reliable solution. (BTW, _Modern C++_ capitalized, generally refers to an influential book by that name, but that no longer is a modern book)